# Executing Hive Query from Java

Tags: java, hive

I tried to execute a small `hive query` from `Java`, but it is failing with below error, bur when I copy the same query and run on terminal it is giving me the result.

Can someone help me on this.

Java Code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("hive -e 'show databases;'");
```

Error thrown:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:5 cannot recognize input near '&lt;EOF&gt;' '&lt;EOF&gt;' '&lt;EOF&gt;' in ddl statement
```

Regards,
GHK.

Comment: I think this is some big problem, I tried in multiple ways, but I couldnt get any solution for this.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem trying to call a hive script from bash. If I find a solution I'll let you know, cause it is the exact same error, so it probably has the same cause.

Comment: OK, updated my answer from before. It now contains the exact reason for the problem, how to fix it, and then some code to get the command working how you want it to.

Answer (score 3):

I have been working with this Java problem for a while, and I believe I have solved this problem. Basically the reason you are failing is because the environment variables are not ser up properly. put the following in your `/home/<username>/.bash_profile` file and restart your machine to fix this.

```
HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive

export HIVE_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive

export PATH
```

This will ensure that they get set up properly.

However while this will get rid of the error it still won't show you a list of databases because the process that runs the hive command will run in the background, not on the console the main program is running from. The following code will let you redirect the outputs of the program to the console that the main program is running from.

```
package testing.console;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder;
import java.util.Map;

import testing.console.OutputRedirector;

//This Works

public class ConsoleTester {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ProcessBuilder hiveProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("hive", "-e",
                "show databases");
        String path = processEnv.get("PATH");
        Process hiveProcess = hiveProcessBuilder.start();

        OutputRedirector outRedirect = new OutputRedirector(
                hiveProcess.getInputStream(), "HIVE_OUTPUT");
        OutputRedirector outToConsole = new OutputRedirector(
                hiveProcess.getErrorStream(), "HIVE_LOG");

        outRedirect.start();
        outToConsole.start();    
    }

}
```

And the OutputRedirector class used to get the output to console.

```
package testing.console;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class OutputRedirector extends Thread {

    InputStream is;
    String type;

    public OutputRedirector(InputStream is, String type){
        this.is = is;
        this.type = type;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(type + "> " + line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioE) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you selecting path and not using it?